# Use Python alongside C# in Windows UWP app

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, uwp, language-interoperability

I started writing an application in Python, but I now want to switch to C# and UWP. I know that you cannot write a UWP app in Python, but I am trying to see if I can write some code in Python and access that code from C#.

For example, writing a class in Python that C# code can access as well. Is that possible? And if so, can Python access Microsoft's UWP APIs?

The main code will not be written in Python; that would be impossible. But can interoperability between C# and Python exist, perhaps with IronPython (.NET's Python)?

And how would I set up such a Visual Studio project? I have Python Tools for Visual Studio installed, but there was no built-in option to add a Python file to my UWP app.

Comment: There is some great [article about integrating a Lua interpreter into UWP](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/10/29/Extend-your-UWP-apps-with-Lua-scripting.aspx) - maybe this can also be done using IronPython?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Classic' python interpreters in c# (as IronPython) don't work in store apps because of framework restrictions, as you run your app through a sandbox.

Some dude has ported the full python interpreter to WinRT [on mercurial](https://hg.python.org/sandbox/loewis/file/ee9f8c546ddd/win8app). Of course, due to framework restrictions, the whole standard library isn't available.
This works with WinRT, so it will very likely work on UWP.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to execute a .exe file in UWP? I have copied ipy.exe and the other files in its directory into my project and am now trying to use C# to execute it.

Comment: Nope, due to sandboxing, executing an embedded or an external executable is absolutely impossible. You need to add the DLLs as shared libraries

Comment: In order to run .exe files that do some specific task for my UWP apps, I have resorted to putting them on Azure and running them behind a RESTful API.  It works pretty well.  Your app makes a REST call to your server which runs the .exe with whatever parameters you stick into the REST call.  It spits the result out and the server sends it back.

Comment: I feel like this needs some corrections for accuracy.

Appcontainer-sandboxed desktop programs can create child processes if they have the right, or - with default rights/permissions - if the appcontainer-sandboxed program is the command-line and the full path to the executable is known. Source: my last few days of experimenting.

Also this link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44006005/7347121

Communication between appcontainer-programs and non-appcontainer-programs can be achieved easily by using inherited handles.