# how to sign out from windows 10 program in uwp?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

how to log off(sign out) windows 10 using uwp?
I have do in win-forms but codes are not working in uwp.

```
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int ExitWindowsEx(int operationFlag, int rationReason);

  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Application.Current.Exit();

            ExitWindowsEx(0, 0);
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to logout of Windows or close the application.  I'm not sure Windows will let you log out from an application it is running.

Comment: yes, i want  to log out from WIndows  using uwp app..

Comment: give a log out button and clear the stacktrace and then redirect the user to the home page

Comment: No, i want to sign out from my system(windows 10) using uwp app..

Comment: UWP applications cannot sign users out or lock the workstation. That would result in a denial of service from an app that just locked the workstation in a tight loop. Also, some device families don't support signing out. (How do you sign out of your phone or fitness band?)

Answer (score 0):

In non-UWP programme You can create a new process and run

```
%windir%\System32\shutdown.exe /l /t 0
```

But this is not available to UWP programmes.  Check out the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925096/how-to-execute-process-commands-or-similar-using-a-universal-windows-platform) link here for another take on this problem.  But it looks like you are out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

As i see your code above , you are actually closing the application. In UWP , Application works on states like **Activated**, **Running**, **Suspended** or **Exited**
If you want to log out from the application , it means that you would like to wipe of all user data and his Navigation History.

Make A function that clears the NavigationTrace and once the NavigationEntry is cleared , navigate the user to the login screen/home page

Comment: i want a sign out button in my uwp app  from there user can sign out or lock  the windows.

Comment: u cant do that . In UWP it is not allowed