# Windows 10 assigned access: how to logout programmatically

Tags: uwp, windows-10, kiosk-mode

I have console app running in background under Assigned Access (Windows 10's Kiosk Mode). By command from main UWP-app it should logoff current user. I've tried 2 ways to do this:

- WinAPI function `ExitWindowsEx(0, 0)`
- `Process.Start("shutdown /l /f")`

Both works well if current user has password. But if user has no password, Windows re-login immediately after logout. Is there a way to avoid re-login?

UPDATE:
Looks like `LockWorkStation` does not working too. May be it for security reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you vary much to @magicandre1981 for answer in comments. His answer:

> [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467587/1466046) call instead of ExitWindows

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Raymond Chen from Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467844/how-to-sign-out-from-windows-10-program-in-uwp#comment60586649_36467844) this is not possible:

> UWP applications cannot sign users out or lock the workstation. That
>   would result in a denial of service from an app that just locked the
>   workstation in a tight loop.

In your Client/Server were UWP app send request to a desktop application, approach try the [WTSDisconnectSession()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383830.aspx) call in the desktop application, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467587/1466046).

Comment: I know it. And I split my app into two: UWP app & Desktop Console App. They communicate over WCF. When user press "Logout" button in UWP-app, it send request to Console app witch executes ```ExitWindowsEx(0, 0)```.

Its works fine but not under Assigned Access mode.

Comment: [try this call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14467587/1466046) instead of ExitWindows

Comment: Thank you vary match magicandre1981!  ```WTSDisconnectSession()``` works great in Kiosk Mode.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found this on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/partnerapps/create-a-kiosk-app-for-assigned-access#add-a-way-out-of-assigned-access-a-nameaddawaya)

It explains how to exit assigned access. 
Get the LockApplicationHost from current view. If host is null, the app doesn't run under assigned access, so it's been started normally. And then call RequestUnlock() and the Login Screen shows and you can log in with different user.

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.LockScreen.LockApplicationHost lockHost = Windows.ApplicationModel.LockScreen.LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView();

if (lockHost != null)
{
    lockHost.RequestUnlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**Log off the current user.**

```
ExitWindows(0, 0);
ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, 0);
```

**With User Interaction**

The application receives the **[WM_QUERYENDSESSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890(v=vs.85).aspx)** message and displays a dialog box asking the whether it is OK to end the session. If the user clicks **Yes**, the system logs off the user. If the user clicks **No**, the logoff is canceled.

```
case WM_QUERYENDSESSION:  
{ 
    int r; 
    r = MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)L"End the session?",(LPCWSTR)L"WM_QUERYENDSESSION",MB_YESNO);

    // Return TRUE to continue, FALSE to stop. 

    return r == IDYES; 
    break; 
}
```

Comment: I have only 2 apps running: UWP & console written on C#.
```ExitWindowsEx``` does not works properly under assigned access mode.