# UWP launch on screen keyboard on button click

Tags: c#-4.0, uwp

I am developing one UWP app where I want on screen to be launched on button click. I want to deploy app in surface tab.
Keyboard is getting visible in Tablet mode when text box is being focused but not in desktop mode.
In UWP System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(".exe") is also not permissible.
So ultimately I am thinking to use button to launch on screen keyboard.
Is there any way to do that?
Kindly helping me out?

Comment: There is no API for the opening on-screen keyboard. Source: [Programatically open On-Screen Keyboard in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618127/programatically-open-on-screen-keyboard-in-uwp)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can run .exe in UWP using [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher). So run `osk.exe` to open on-screen keyboard. Check the above link for more info.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT So is there is any other way to open on-screen keyboard?

Comment: Actually I misread "Surface tab" as "Surface Hub" but maybe you meant "Surface tablet" (like a Surface Pro?). If you meant a Surface tablet, running the Desktop OS, you could include a full-trust component that launched the keyboard (you can't use `FullTrustProcessLauncher` directly, since that can only run apps in your package). You might have trouble if you want to submit to the Windows Store though.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT So this question has no answer. Am I right?

Comment: Thank you for giving such useful replies.There no full proof way to do this either.