# Is there a way to show Touch Screen Keyboard in UWP app when there is a Hardware Keyboard- Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I am developing UWP application for windows 10 OS. I need to show touch screen keyboard when user click on a text box.

Following are the requirements.

1.Windows 10 OS

2.Tablet mode off

3.Hardware Keyboard is attached.

I have go through the Microsoft sample https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TouchKeyboard. But could not find a solution.

I have enabled “show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there’s no keyboard attached”  keyboard setting. As it says it only works when there is no hardware  keyboard attached.

But I need to show the touch screen keyboard while there is a hardware keyboard as well

I tried to use  InputPane as following code sample:

**MainPage.xaml**

`< TextBox x:Name="text1" Width="300" Height="50" ></TextBox>`

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
   {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        text1.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(text1_Tapped), true);
   }


 private void text1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        InputPane pane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
        pane.TryShow();
   }
```

That also not showing touch screen keyboard when hardware keyboard is attached .

Please guide me to solve this requirement.

Comment: See if anything in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618127/programmatically-open-on-screen-keyboard-in-uwp) helps

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to show Touch Screen Keyboard in UWP app when there is a Hardware Keyboard- Windows 10

Derive from this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618127/programmatically-open-on-screen-keyboard-in-uwp), we could not launch Touch Screen Keyboard within UWP desktop model. But we could launch wpf app and then call `osk.exe` indirectly.

For integrating wpf app into UWP, we could refer this [tutorial](https://stefanwick.com/2018/05/15/global-hotkey-registration-in-uwp/).  And communicate with wpf client by UWP `AppService`.

We could send message to tell wpf client to launch [`osk.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28253871/7254781) when the TextBox focused from UWP `Client`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Show/Hide the On Screen Keyboard in Desktop Mode by using CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().TryShow(CoreInputViewKind.Keyboard).

Code Sample:

.xaml:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="TextBox_OnGotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_OnLostFocus" InputScope="Number"/>
```

.xaml.cs:

```
private void TextBox_OnGotFocus(object _, RoutedEventArgs __)
{
    CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().TryShow(CoreInputViewKind.Keyboard);
}

private void TextBox_OnLostFocus(object _, RoutedEventArgs __)
{
    CoreInputView.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();
}
```

Additionally, you can control the keyboard type by setting the InputScope with values like: Number, NumericPin, Text, or others: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.InputScopeNameValue