# How to specify classic key board layout in UWP app

Tags: uwp, keyboard, keyboard-layout, inputscope, soft-input-panel

I want to specify classic touch keyboard layout(one with number bar on top) in
login page of my UWP app.
[image]

I understand that it can be done by specifying InputScope="NameOrPhoneNumber" etc.

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/use-input-scope-to-change-the-touch-keyboard 

 My question is what InputScopeNameValue should I used to get classic keyboard.

 Tried AlphanumericFullWidth (41) which is the logical option, but it does not work.

#Edit : Attaching keyboard layout
[image]

Comment: This is the default keyboard layout of the on-screen keyboard. You need to enable the on-screen keyboard in the Settings. Check [Programmatically open On-Screen Keyboard in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618127/programmatically-open-on-screen-keyboard-in-uwp)

Comment: Actually this app is running on MS Surface tabs. When testing on desktop (development PC's) we have enabled show touch keyboard.

Comment: Client request is to display classic keyboard on login screen and default keyboard on other pages. Issue is we cant do this programmatically from XML or Code as follows
■ XML
<TextBox Header="EmpID" InputScope="AlphanumericFullWidth"/>
■Code
empID.InputScope = new InputScope() 
{
    Names = {new InputScopeName(InputScopeNameValue.AlphanumericFullWidth)}
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that you can't set the keyboard style programmatically from your app. This is a setting inside the keyboard itself and it is controlled by the system.

Comment: I kind of have come to the same realization. For a selected keyboard layout, I can use InputScope to control some parameters like displaying Japanese or English keyboard, Displaying Number or URL entry keyboard. But that also depends on which keyboard layout user have selected. For example, if user have selected Default keyboard, options are high. For classic keyboard layout, most of the options does not work.