# Run console app from Windows XAML app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i run hidden console application with parameters from universal windows application (VS2017), and redirect it's output into textblock/textblock?

I've found many examples with Process, but looks like all this examples written for console applications running another console applications.

In detail: this is UNIVERSAL WINDOWS APPLICATION, not standart or wpf app, there is no such element as Process and i can't add this from using. UWP just does not has this in libraries.

I want to know is there any way to comunicate with another process (console process) from UWP app.

Comment: The following doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Comment: @isma Nope, it doesn't. I didn't see Process anywhere, i've imported Diagnostics and other stuff, but there still error on a 'Process'

Comment: Provide some code including what you have tried.

Comment: @Isma the recomendations from answer above, like this:
    using System.Diagnostics;
    .....
    Process p = new Process();

then i've got: https://i.imgur.com/HShJlHC.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest method of inter-process communication between 2 C# processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro)

Comment: Windows 10 tablet programs doesn't support the `Process` object, and have severely limited capabilities. See this for some (nasty) workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33925096/2557263

Answer (score 0):

From @Alejandro: Windows 10 tablet programs doesn't support the Process object, and have severely limited capabilities. See this for some (nasty) workarounds: stackoverflow.com/q/33925096/2557263