# Access denied error for Process.Start inside .NET Standard library referenced in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard

In my `VS2017` solution, I created a `UWP` and `.NET Standard Library 2.0.3` projects. Referenced Library project from UWP. Library project is using a `System.Diagnostics.Process` to start a process. In debug mode, I get access denied error at line `Process.Start(...)` of the code inside Library project.

I thought the purpose of new .NET Standard Library project was to support various platforms (.NET, .NET Core, UWP etc) uniformly. But I guess, the sandbox nature of UWP apps is probably not allowing me to run `Process.Start(...)` albeit the process is running inside Library project. Question: What I may be missing and/or how can we resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot launch process directly from UWP, but there are some alternative ways to do that. The first one is using [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher), if you need some example, check this [post](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) series. Another way is using a WPF or WinForms application to host UWP Controls with the [Xaml Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands) where there aren't restrictions to call any .NET APIs, but remember, through this way, your app will work only on Desktop devices.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33925585/4403297), you can't use `Process.Start` in a UWP app. There are some alternatives for launching other apps, but you can't execute arbitrary `.exe` or other processes.