# Universal Windows Platform (UWP) C# app - How to run stand alone python inside your application

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am trying to find a way to call python from my UWP app. So far I have a .exe file that I have compiled from python using pyinstaller (www.pyinstaller.org/). This basically allows me to package up my python script as a standalone binary (ie: you don't need python to run it). This all works well and I can call my wrapped up python .exe via cmd.exe no problem:

> $ process.exe -p "path\to\file"
>
> $ Processing file: "path\to\file"...
>
> $ Done.

So now I just need to call it from my UWP app - so I have added it to my application like so:

> C# Project
>
> > Assets/process.exe

Frustratingly, I've not had much luck googling for answers to my problem - my attempted solutions so far have included:

- Calling the "Assets/process.exe" directly from my app
- Looked at "Launch an app and get results". I think this seams to be for external applications however... I certainly didn't get it going anyway.
- Opening the cmd.exe (somehow) and calling my process.exe from there.

I'm not even sure if I'm trying to do this the correct way or not. Or if I have just not understood some of my findings. Or (fingers crossed) there is a simple solution to this I just don't know about and have somehow missed as I'm very new to UWP development and C#.

So any solutions/pointers here would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP apps are 'sandboxed'; i.e. they have many security restrictions placed upon them to isolate them from the rest of Windows (like not being able to read/write to the Registry and not being able to directly access random files from the file system).

So there is no way to run an `.exe` (or any other executable) from your UWP app. If you have access to a `StorageFile` (say music, video or any other file format) then you can [launch the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701471.aspx) in the default program associated with that file type.

Comment: Hi Aniruddha Varma - Thanks very much for your quick response! 

Ok that makes sense. So do you (or anyone) know of any other way I can get my Python code and dependencies to run inside a UWP project? Eg: another file format accessible to my UWP app that I can compile my Python app to. 
Or am I using the wrong project type entirely? 
Or is what I am trying to do currently impossible and the only way around this would be to rewrite my python program entirely in c#?

Comment: Also to clarify - I'm really only worried about a desktop app at this time.

Comment: @WilliamTonkin-Howe You could just develop a desktop app (WPF or WinForms - which don't have any security restrictions). You can integrate python libraries (I've not tried this personally) into .NET using Iron Python (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython).

Comment: @WilliamTonkin-Howe If you want to use only UWP, it might be tough to get python code working alongside it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457554/use-python-alongside-c-sharp-in-windows-uwp-app